# Addition in selecting multiple values

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

The below code is a multiple select form where it is done till values will be selected.I need addtion of the selected values to show when ever i am selecting the selected.
i mean if i select item1 and item2 it should give sum as 223 dynamically uisng jquery in the same page.i think css has to be used.Help me out in this calculation of suming in selecting multiple values.Any tutorials regarding this are encouragble.

```
    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {

          });
    });



</script>



<form>
  <fieldset>

    <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
      <option value="111">Item 1</option>
      <option value="112">Item 2</option>
      <option value="113">Item 3</option>
      <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    </select>

    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>

    </select>

  </fieldset>
</form>'
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
$('#select-from option:selected').each( function(i, v) {
    sum += parseInt($(v).attr('value'), 10);
      });
alert(sum);
```

Should do it.

You can check the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gBYSe/).

Answer (score 0):

This will update the `selectedTotal` each time an `option` is selected/unselected (I think that's what you wanted?)

```
$selectOptions = $('option', '#select-from');

$selectOptions.click(function() {   
  var selectedTotal = 0;

  $selectOptions.filter(':selected').each(function() {
    selectedTotal += parseInt(this.value);
  });

  $('#total').text(selectedTotal);  
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KzBYS/12/)

Comment: Hey you demo is not working when i am trying to select each value...can you please checkout once again your code...thank you